# Unit testing - Flurl , How to mock flurl request response?

Tags: c#, api, tdd, flurl

**Main service implementation using flurl**

```
Public async Task<ApplicationItemVm> UpdateOpportunityInfo(string optyNumber, UpdateOpportunityVm model, string token = "")
    {
     
            var result = await "https://api.com/*"
                 .WithOAuthBearerToken(token)
                .PatchJsonAsync(model)
                .ReceiveJson<ApplicationItemVm>();
            return result;
   
    }
```

**Test Method using MS Test**

```
 [TestMethod]
    public async Task UpdateOppTest()
    {
       var updateOpportunityVm = new UpdateOpportunityVm
        {
            AboutYouIConfirm_c = true
        };

        var applicationItemVm = new ApplicationItemVm { AboutYouIConfirm_c=true};

        // fake & record all http calls in the test subject
        using (var httpTest = new HttpTest())
        {
            // arrange
            httpTest.
                RespondWith("OK", 200).RespondWithJson(applicationItemVm);
            // act
            var application = await applicationService.UpdateOpportunityInfo("optyNumber", updateOpportunityVm, "CloudToken");
            // assert
            httpTest.ShouldHaveCalled("https://api.com/*")
                .WithVerb(HttpMethod.Patch)
                .WithContentType("application/json");
        }

    }
```

After test method execution got following error

Response could nor deserilize

Let me know if I need to add more details.

Please suggest what's wrong I am doing.

**Expected Result**
I want to mock request and response when I calling the main service method but unfortunately I not able to do

Comment: Could you post a stack trace with that exception?

Comment: Hi Todd,  I fixed null exception, The main issue is I am not able to mock request response of flurl when calling main method implementation.

Expected Result:-
 I want to mock request and response when I calling the main service method but unfortunately I not able to do

Comment: please let me know how can I setup mock for IFlurlRequest and IFlurlResponse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the arrange step of your test:

```
httpTest.RespondWith("OK", 200).RespondWithJson(applicationItemVm);
```

Every call to `RespondWith*` will add a new fake response to the queue, so here you're enqueuing 2 responses. When the HTTP call is made in your test subject, Flurl will dequeue the first one and fake the call with that response, so you're getting `"OK"` back in the response body, which obviously won't JSON-desrialize to your `ApplicationItemVm` type. That's where the failure is occuring.

To fix this, just enqueue a single response in your arrange step:

```
httpTest.RespondWithJson(applicationItemVm, 200);
```

200 is the default for fake responses so you could even leave that out unless you like it there for readability.

Comment: Hey, it's working like a charm.
Thanks, Todd, appreciated!